# Incorrect transition between activities

Tags: java, android

Probably something I do not understand.

In the application programs (from google play), if we move from the main activity to the second and then back to the main, then after pressing the "back" button on the phone, the application closes.

I tried to make my own applications with two activities, but it did not work as it should. When the main activity goes to the second and then I go back to the main, then after pressing the "back" button on the phone, the application instead of closing, it goes back to the second activity, then back to the main and it just closes.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button Act2Butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Act2Butt);

        Act2Butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Button Act1Butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Act1Butt);

    Act1Butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class );
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go back to MainActivity from Main2Activity, you need to call `onBackPressed()` or `finish()`, instead of `startActivity`.